# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.models.target_python'

Tags: pip, python-3.12

I installed Python 3.12.1 on my 64-bit Windows 10 machine. Python reports sucessful install. However, when I run "pip install pyqt5" from a CMD window I get the following;

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.models.target_python'
```

Can anyone suggest a fix?

I tried various workarounds plus a reinstall of pip, but nothing fixed the problem.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940813/pip-no-module-named-internal

Comment: What are outputs of python3 —version, pip —version and python3 -m pip —version? I suspect some mismatch or multiple pip versions

Comment: Uninstall all versions of Python. Reboot PC. Install latest Python and when you do go to Options or Advanced during installation and check to install pip and also check the box to add to path to environment variable. Then reboot PC again and it should work.