# Python pip package RequestsDependencyWarning when installing elastic-search-curator

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pip, elasticsearch-curator

I installed elastic search curator via the following command.

```
sudo pip install -U elasticsearch-curator
```

It all installed OK.

However now when I do the following

```
curator_cli --version
```

I get the following dependency warning.

```
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
curator_cli, version 5.5.4
```

How do I either fix the warning or hide it?

Comment: You may need to update cryptography as well

Comment: I got this when trying to compile the YouCompleteMe plugin for `vim`. The answer was the answer for me, too.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

So took a couple of things for me to get this working.

First I upgraded cyptography as per Mufeeds suggestion

```
sudo pip install --upgrade cryptography
```

This then gave me a new error everytime I did `pip <any command>`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

Resolved this by resintalling PyOpenSSL

```
sudo python -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```

Curator is now working as expected without the warnings

```
curator_cli --version
> curator_cli, version 5.5.4
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Anything older than Python 2.7.9 is likely to have issues, as there are SNI and other SSL complications.  Travis CI tests Curator with the most recent patch levels of 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6.  I'll be adding 3.7 support soon.

Comment: Running on Python 2.7.13.

Comment: How was this installed on which operating system?  Very strange that a 2.7.13 Python wouldn't have the appropriate modules updated.

Comment: installed it all with sudo apt install

Comment: On which operating system? I can see that it's Debian or Debian derived.

Comment: ubuntu 16 I think.  was a while ago now

Comment: In all honesty, if you are using Ubuntu or Debian, I'd recommend using Elastic's provided DEB packages, which are stand-alone (i.e. will not interfere with system Python in any way) and built with a very recent version of Python. There is a repo and a direct download available: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/apt-repository.html#_direct_package_download_link

Comment: im pretty sure I did use that - I followed steps on the elastic website.  Maybe the issue here is that I already had python and some kind of conflict arose.  However its a while ago now and the ubuntu versions have changes.

Answer (score 0):

This 1st step below will update cryptography, but break pyopenssl.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade cryptography
```

We can fix that by removing the pyopennssl library and use pip to reinstall.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.15.1.egg-info
sudo pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
sudo pip install cryptography --upgrade
```

The last line will produce an error if the open sll library were to still be broken, so this validates all should be well...

My preference is to avoid another package manage like easy install in the mix, so sharing this in case that is anyone else's preference as well.