# The program sudo cannot be found

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and was having the a issues similar to the one mentioned on this 
[sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

I was trying the solution of Tyler Rick and issued this command 
sudo mv /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sudo.orig

Quite stupid of me. Now I cannot run sudo anymore because the system throws an error

```
The program 'sudo' can be found in the follow
 * sudo
 * sudo-ldap
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `/usr/bin/sudo.orig` instead of `sudo`.

Comment: sometimes stupidity sees no bounds. Thanks for your answer. How can I change it back from sudo.orig to sudo ?

Comment: Undo the `mv`...? `mv /usr/bin/sudo.orig /usr/bin/sudo`