# Ubuntu change sudo php path

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-4, lampp

I was struggling with apache2 already installed in ubuntu so I decided to return back to lampp..I have unistalled apache 2 mysql server and phpmyadmin.
The problem is that when I type `sudo which php`
I get nothing...

So I cannot request e.g. `sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel.....`

since php is missing for root user..

Although when I type `which php` I get /opt/lampp/bin/php..

Is it possible to make the root user use the same path..?

Comment: Generally, it's better not to use the root user whenever you can. Is there a chance you can install laravel as a regular user and drop sudo completely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does sudo change the PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/257616/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

Switch to root user

```
sudo su -
```

Edit the .bashrc

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

And add a new path to the current one:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```