# virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I am rather new to Linux (Ubuntu) and installing (Python) packages. I'm having trouble with mkvirtualenv and can not solve it:

```
~$ mkvirtualenv mysite70
New python executable in mysite70/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 562, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 544, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 271, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 246, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 236, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 577, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 476, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 355, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /home/sietse/.virtualenvs/mysite70/local/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)
ERROR: The executable mysite70/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/home/usr/.virtualenvs' (should be u'/home/usr/.virtualenvs/mysite70')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Did I install something wrong?

Comment: try running the `mk` command with `sudo`. lets make  sure it is not a permission error like often is in linux.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a permissions error with your current logged in user on the Linux machine.

Try

```
sudo mkvirtualenv mysite70
```

This will often prompt for the password of the root user.

If that does not work, you may want to look at the article below:

http://noelusion.com/2013/Fixing-the-mysterious-virtualenv-error-IOError-invalid-Python-installation/

But note, that the article is a hack on a fairly specific instance.

Comment: I did this and get:~$ sudo mkvirtualenv mysite70
sudo: mkvirtualenv: command not found

Comment: sudo can changed you $PATH variable on ubuntu. Check your $PATH variable after sudo. If it is not what you expect, follow the post below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Comment: ...I do not know what to expect...just know that it gives "mkvirtualenv: command not found"...
When I follow your link, I do and get:
~$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sh
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
and:
~$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

This path seems ok to me!? Any idea why the command is not found? Did I install Python 'outside su domain' or something; how do I 'repair'? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I messed up the installation. I reinstalled Ubuntu, virtualenv etc. It works fine now.

Comment: OK, but it would also probably work if you purged and reinstalled the relevant packages (python-virtualenv virtualenvwrapper), deleted the old .virtualenvs folder and created the virtualenv from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your username has accents or special characters. If yes, change directory creating environments creating an environment variable WORKON_HOME with value equal to the new path. Ex .: C:\Envs