# Issue with activating virtualenv

Tags: bash, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv

I installed python environment by means of commands:

```
SYS_INSTALL="apt-get install -y"
PIP_INSTALL="pip install"

# Be sure to install setuptools before pip to properly replace easy_install.
$SYS_INSTALL git 
$SYS_INSTALL python-dev
$SYS_INSTALL python-setuptools
$SYS_INSTALL python-pip
$PIP_INSTALL virtualenv
```

also was able to create new virtual environment:

```
virtualenv .env
```

However, after running a command like:

```
. .env/bin/activate
```

I got

> -bash: .env/bin/activate: No such file or directory

After reviewing folder `.env/bin` I found only one `python` file. Whole list of files here:

```
.env/lib:
python2.7

.env/include:
python2.7

.env/bin:
python
```

What is the issue here?

**SOLUTION** add `--always-copy`

> virtualenv .env --always-copy

Comment: this has solved my issue : venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory as setup was not building bin directory

Comment: This question is tagged with Ubuntu, but if you're on Windows see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206990/virtualenv-env-not-creating-bin-directory-in-windows-7

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The accepted answer is incomplete! The suggested code left out your error, but didn't comment on it.

The command `. .env/bin/activate` would indeed do the same as `source` on the file `activate` in the folder `.env/bin`. In fact, apparently the command "`source`" is an alias for the command "`.`", and not the other way around. Note that `.` here has a space after it, and used differently from the `.` discussed below (which makes files and folders hidden).

What I notice is that you are calling your folder `.env`, which is not standard practice. Files and folders preceded by `.` are made "hidden" by Mac OS X. Standard practice is to call a virtual environment **directory** `env` or `venv`, and to call the virtual environment specification **file** `.env`.

So, if your spec file is called `.env` and your virtual environment directory is called `env`, you can run either

`source env/bin/activate`
or
`. env/bin/activate`.

Answer (score 42):

For me it works when I do these steps:

- Go to the directory/folder that you want
- run `virtualenv .env`
- then run `source .env/bin/activate`

Comment: why is that worked?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and the following steps resolved it:

```sh
$mkdir annotateNLP
$cd annotateNLP
$python -m venv env
$source env/Scripts/activate
```

Comment: YES ! It seems some of us have a Scripts/ folder instad of a bin/. Not sure if this is unique to python3.8 or windows or something

Comment: `Scripts` directory should be for Windows. On Unix-like systems (this question is about) the directory with executables is `bin`.

Answer (score 8):

Try these commands in the terminal:

```
$ mkdir djangoapp
$ cd djangoapp
$ python3 -m venv myvenv
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
```

You can't go straight into activate command without first creating your virtual environment.

Answer (score 5):

you forgot to include `source` before activating command is
`source env/bin/activate`

this question is similar to your's
[virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686626/virtualenv-is-not-compatible-with-this-system-or-executable)
where it creates virtualenv but,`python` file instead of `activate` in bin

Comment: I believe issue here `.env/bin/activate: No such file or directory`. I don't have this file after running command `virtualenv .env`

Comment: try creating the file name without dot like virtualenv env

Comment: try creating virtualenv with sudo or in root it works good or take a look at this link          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686626/virtualenv-is-not-compatible-with-this-system-or-executable

Answer (score 3):

After going to your virtual environment folder `.\Scripts\activate`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I need to install

`sudo apt-get install python3-venv`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same issue. I uninstalled the virtualenv in Ubuntu and then I installed it again. After this nonsense, it works and now I am able to activate my virtualenv through `-$source py3/bin/activate`.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ virtualenv env
$ cd env/Scripts/
$ . activate
```

Answer (score 0):

If installed venv on a Windows machine, run this command (assuming you are in the working directory that has your venv folder):

- In bash terminal: source venv/Scripts/activate
- In cmd terminal:
  venv\Scripts\activate

where venv is the folder name for your virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

For windows using git bash, run the below command:-

```
source env\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The `source venv/bin/activate` didn't work for me.

The activate file for me was in the `venv/scripts/` folder.

So I simply changed the code to `source venv/scripts/activate`
And it worked.

Basically try looking for the activate file and specify the location.

Comment: This is not significantly different from existing answers to warrant a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, It works for me:

```
$ mkdir my_project
$ cd my_project
$ python -m venv env
$ source env/bin/activate
```

at Line 3 and 4 **env** should be same. If you name it **venv** should use:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same error, and as a best practice, I consistently refer to updated documentation to ensure that I'm using the most recent version of the command.

[image]

The command I attempted to use to activate the virtual environment is designed for Unix/macOS systems. However, since I am using Windows OS, the correct command differs. Unfortunately, the command provided in the documentation did not work for me.

[image]

Since I am using Git Bash in VSCode, the source command will indeed work, as Git Bash allows users to execute many Unix/Linux commands directly within its terminal environment.

Therefore,  I managed to resolve the problem by issuing the following command:

[image]

I successfully resolved the issue by consulting this [documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#activate-a-virtual-environment).