# Python venv/bin/activate popping no such file or directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to activate my venv and it keeps popping no such file or directory.

```
bash: tutorial-env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python. I've made the venv with the name tutorial-env. This is entirely just a test as I'm new to python and attempting to use pip modules.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137664/issue-with-activating-virtualenv

Comment: For this to be answerable, we'd need to see a much longer transcript -- the command you used to create the venv, its output, the command you use to activate the venv, any other commands you ran between the two. (If you don't know what you ran between the two or have the output of the creation process available, delete the venv and start over, keeping a proper transcript)

Comment: Also, which operating system are you running? When you talk about "uninstalling and reinstalling Python", that implies you're on something like Windows (on MacOS and most Unixlikes Python is part of the OS itself and can't be uninstalled without breaking your OS vendor's tools). If you're on Windows, it matters immensely whether your Python interpreter is native to Cygwin (or whatever's providing bash) or is native-win32.

Comment: And, well, _is_ there a `tutorial-env/bin/activate` file? If there isn't one, but the creation was otherwise successful, that implies that your virtualenv was created for a non-UNIXy operating system (for example, on Windows there'll be `activate.bat` instead)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.