# Error sudo: gem: command not found

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, sudo

I'm trying to install rubyrep on CentOS, and when executing `sudo gem install rubyrep` I get the error `sudo: gem: command not found`.  Sudo and gem are both installed and working, just not when combined.

My setting:

```
[rubyrep]# which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
[rubyrep]# which gem
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/gem
[rubyrep]# which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
[rubyrep]# $PATH
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: nicooga, not using sudo did the trick.  If you post it as an answer I will be able to accept it.

Comment: @nicooga ping. (15 characters)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try without `sudo`. You should only use `sudo` if you did a root installation of ruby, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 8):

From http://web.archive.org/web/20130405074724/http://www.kleinfelter.com/node/188:

> There are hundreds of reports on the net about "sudo: gem: command not
>   found".  Out of the dozen or so I looked at, the suggested resolution
>   amounted to "ensure that 'gem' is in your PATH."
>
> Yep.  It is in my path.  That is to say, the following works:
>
> gem --help
>
> but the following fails:
>
> sudo gem --help
>
> Further confusing matters, gem is in the path shown by:
>
> sudo echo $PATH
>
> The trick is that sudo doesn't use $PATH for its path on some editions
>   of Linux.  This behavior is considered "more secure."  (See
>   [sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why) ).
>
> Bah!  It is still a pain to work around.  You have to get 'gem' into
>   the path (not simply the $PATH!)  You'll read about options you can
>   pass to sudo, and that is fine and dandy when you type the
>   command-line yourself.  When someone's script invokes sudo for you,
>   you're stuck with the command line that it uses.

I fixed it by doing:

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

as suggested in [sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why).

Answer (score 6):

sudo env PATH=$PATH  gem install  rails

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs across this, like I did, and the without sudo isn't an option. You may want to check your sudoers for the 'secure_path'.

If this doesn't include the path of your installation/gem/ruby (which gem). Then you'll also get this error.

Fedora 23, built from source.