# How to install rails with sudo gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
$ gem install rails
```

> ```
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>     You don't have write permissions for the /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0 directory.
> ```

```
$ sudo gem install rails
sudo: gem: command not found
$ gem -v
2.6.12
```

Why `sudo gem install rails` result in command not found?
How to install rails now?

```
user@debian:~$ su root
Password: 
root@debian:/home/user# gem install rails
bash: gem: command not found
```

Comment: refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/24706277/6521116  and answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757932/6521116 to check it.

Comment: check who is the current user using `whoami` and then do 
`ll /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0` and check who is the owner

Answer (score 0):

You can use the root user,

```
su root
gem install rails
```