# Change default python to anaconda's python in root

Tags: python, ubuntu, path, sudo, anaconda

I've installed python 2.7 in my system and I've installed Anaconda also. 
Right now, I am using python's anaconda and it works perfect. Unfortunately, I wanted to use anaconda's python to be run using root. The issue is that I was unable to change the python path for root.

If I type "`which python`" from terminal , I am able to get this result:

```
/home/myuser/anaconda/bin/python
```

If I type "`sudo which python`" from terminal, the result is :

```
/usr/bin/python
```

I have installed anaconda in a directory accessible by root (changed during installation) and I've already added it's path to `/etc/environment`(added `/usr/anaconda/bin` to PATH in environment).

**How do I change the default python path of root(I use `sudo` command to get root privileges)?**

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As any user also root has a  `.bashrc` where you can set the `PATH` variable appropriately.

Comment: how about using a symlink?

Comment: @cel I've already added the PATH using /etc/environment file. I thought, it is enough. Do I have to add that path in .bashrc also?

Comment: @cel I'm sorry that I used the word root. Actually, I was using sudo to get root privileges.

Comment: Could be related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/why-is-path-reset-in-a-sudo-command

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/257616/161801

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Actually, I was installing my script using sudo, which automatically made sudo python path to it's reference. That was the reason why it chose sudo python reference and ended up with problems in running it. I removed sudo from the installation script and for now, it works, as there is no issue in running the script as a user.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly call the python install you'd like to run:

```
sudo /opt/anaconda/bin/python
```

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/477987/two-python-distributions-sudo-picking-the-wrong-one.

Comment: That's why I was getting `no module named asyncio`. One up.