# Confusion regarding setting python executable variable for sudo

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, redhat, sudo

I always want to run this `/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python` executable whenever any of the system user runs below command:

```
python
python3
sudo python
sudo python3
```

I've modified `/etc/environment` file to below value

```
PATH="/anaconda/anaconda3/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
```

All `which pyhton` patterns returns the expected path

```
$ which python
/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python
$ which python3
/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python3
$ sudo which python
/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python
$ sudo which python3
/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

But when I run them with `sudo`, it is not executing `/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python`

```
$ sudo python --version
Python 2.7.5
# This is I believe /bin/python
$ sudo python3 --version
Python 3.6.7
# This is I believe /bin/python3. This is certainly not `/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python`
```

I want to execute `/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python` when any of the user runs `sudo python` or `sudo python3`.

Does this mean `/etc/environment` isn't being able to change `secure_path` for `sudo`?

Please suggest a solution.

My OS is:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.5 (Maipo)"
...
...
```

Comment: Is the `secure_path` option set in `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: @KyleWillmon Yes, there is. Do I have to modify it? Actually, I didn't find a straight forward way to update it so I can put it in Ansible task. I need to automate this configuration.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to modify that if you want to change the path that `sudo` uses. You can read on this topic at the [many](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/why-is-path-reset-in-a-sudo-command), [many](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path), [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/why-does-sudo-change-the-path/375780) asked about this

Comment: @KyleWillmon I've gone through some of them. But why `sudo which python` reveals `/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python` which means it respects `/etc/environment` overrides.

Comment: It's possible that `which` is an alias on your system (try `type which` to find out). You might get a more reliable result if you use `sudo /usr/bin/which python`. You could also do something like `sudo /bin/sh -c 'command -v python'`.