# Linux $PATH is different for the same user, depending on how it is accessed

Tags: php, linux, cron, environment-variables

I have a php script running in a cronjob on the server.

However, I am unexpectedly getting different $PATH from the same user, depending on how I execute the command.

I log in as user `ubuntu`:

```
ubuntu@:$ echo $PATH 
/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.3.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I then `sudo su bitbucket`:

```
bitbucket@:$ echo $PATH
/home/bitbucket/.nvm/versions/node/v12.3.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I execute a script from a cronjob running as bitbucket and output the following debug to a log file:

```
$ whoami
bitbucket
```

The above proves the user is bitbucket, then:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin
```

Please note I am not running as sudo. I am utilising sudo to switch user, but not using sudo to `echo $PATH`.

**How is it that the same user has 2 different $PATH variables?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does sudo change the PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/257616/608639)

Comment: Maybe, it doesn't deserve a downvote that quick. I had that vote less than 5 seconds after it was posted. Assuming you didn't read the content.

Comment: Checked, I am not using sudo. This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which shell you're using so I'm going to assume it's `bash`. The first, and perhaps most important, thing to note is that when you run `sudo su bitbucket` you're getting an interactive shell. Which means that *~/.bashrc* will be sourced. Lots of people modify `PATH` in that script. Something that tends to cause problems. Why? Because non-interactive shells, such as the one launched by cron to run your command, won't read *~/.bashrc*.

Your cron job gets a PATH equivalent to running this command: `sudo su bitbucket -c 'echo $PATH'`. Play around with that to get a better understanding of how this works. For example, instead of `echo $PATH` try `env`.