# Jenkins uses different version of Maven than cmd

Tags: maven, jenkins

First I installed Maven version 3.0.5 on our build system and then I upgraded it to 3.6.0 following this guide https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-apache-maven-on-centos-7/ . Using the cmdline on the system executing:

```
mvn -v
```

I always get 3.6.0 as the version. But when executing the same command in a Jenkins job I get 3.0.5 . So somewhere it looks like it still refers to the older version. But I have no clue where. Any ideas how to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you see in the shell depends on your `PATH` variable.

Jenkins can handle multiple installations of maven.
To configure it:

- Open the Jenkins dashboard.
- Go to Manage Jenkins.
- Go to Global Tool Configuration
- Go to the Maven section and click Maven installations

When adding a new installation, you have 2 options:

- install a selected version automatically
- use existing installation on your system

Then, when configuring a project in jenkins, you can select one of the configured installations.

- For Maven Project under Build / Maven Version
- For Freestyle project under Build Steps / Build / Invoke top level maven targets / Maven Version

Comment: Is there a way to make Jenkins just use the Maven as the PATH variable? I would like to use mvn in a Freestyle Project instead of a Maven project

Comment: Updated my answer, you can use any existing installation from your system (but I think you must be explicit and point it to the correct directory)

Comment: I was able to proceed thanks to your answer but I have another issue now. I noticed that when I'm logged in to the system as the jenkins user and I perform 'sudo mvn -v' I get a different version compared to when executing without sudo. How can I make this sudo jenkins user also make use of mvn 3.6.0 instead of 3.0.5?

Comment: Sudo changes PATH on many distributions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/why-does-sudo-change-the-path

Comment: I did not try your last comment but I just found a workaround which also works out fine for me. As with sudo it used /usr/share/maven and I wanted to use /opt/maven I now just use following command 'sudo /opt/maven/bin/mvn' to execute maven. This works fine and uses sudo + v3.6.0 .