# Command not found when running as other user with sudo

Tags: postgresql, psql, sudo, fish

I am trying to run `psql` with user `postgres`. When I run `sudo su - postgres` AND THEN  `psql` from within the new session, it is working smoothly. In fact, the `~/.bashrc` in that session with use `postgres` has the correct `PATH`.

However, if I run `sudo -u postgres psql`, I get `sudo: psql: command not found`. Even though the session where I am running this command (I use the FISH shell) has the correct PATH as well, and I can invoke `psql` without the full path with my user.

I need to invoke the command as `sudo -u postgres psql`, how can this behavior be explained?

Edit: if (from FISH) I switch to BASH and run `sudo -u postgres psql`, it works! I guess it has to do with the FISH path then...

Edit 2: The issue seems to be that the PATH is reset when using `sudo`.

```
➜  ~ psql
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "opc" does not exist
➜  ~ sudo -u postgres psql
sudo: psql: command not found
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/home/opc/.local /home/opc/.local/bin /usr/pgsql-15/bin /usr/pgsql-15/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/sbin
➜  ~ sudo echo $PATH
/home/opc/.local /home/opc/.local/bin /usr/pgsql-15/bin /usr/pgsql-15/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/sbin
➜  ~ sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/psql
could not change directory to "/home/opc": Permission denied
psql (15.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

But if I echo $PATH with sudo, it seems fine...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572018/3150338 - sudo might change $PATH, and if you're using bash it's simply read from .bashrc again.

Comment: I tried, but the result is the same. I realised that, regardless of which user I run the command with, the PATH gets reset. Even when running `sudo psql`, I get command not found.
Even if I run `sudo -E psql`, I get command not found...

Comment: Have you tried telling sudo to knock it off by disabling that "secure_path" feature?

Comment: On my (Debian) system sudoers has an "Defaults env_reset" line followed a bit later by a line that says "Defaults secure_path=something". You'll want to comment that one out and add a new line `Defaults !secure_path`

Comment: Ok by commenting that one line it works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a `sudo` configuration that has the "secure_path" setting. This causes sudo to reset $PATH to a hardcoded "known safe" value. This might be enabled by your distribution.

When you run `sudo bash`, that bash will read its settings, including .bashrc, and if you set $PATH in that it will then, of course, have that $PATH again.

But if you run a command without going through a shell that resets $PATH, you'll get the hardcoded setting.

It's possible to change that setting by running `sudo visudo` and changing the line that says

```
Defaults secure_path="some:path:here"
```

to

```
Defaults !secure_path
```

An alternative is to just run the command via the fully qualified path, like

```
sudo -u postgres (command -s psql)
```

---

One more comment about your tests:

> sudo echo $PATH

This doesn't do what you want. The $PATH will be expanded by the shell that runs sudo, and so sudo won't ever see anything but the value of it. It is exactly equivalent to running `sudo echo /home/opc/.local /home/opc/.local/bin /usr/pgsql-15/bin ...`.

You might want to use something like

```
sudo env
```

or

```
sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'
```

instead.

Comment: Changing `Defaults secure_path="some:path:here"` to `Defaults !secure_path` did the job, thanks!