# `node version` and `sudo node version` give different results?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

How can it be that my installed node version is 18.17.0 -

```bash
$ node --version
v18.17.0
```

but still trying to install packages gives me this?

```bash
$ sudo -E npm i dependency-cruiser
npm WARN cli npm v10.2.0 does not support Node.js v18.16.0. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'dependency-cruiser@14.1.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.17||>=20' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.16.0', npm: '10.2.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
...
```

`n doctor` seems ok, this is after `nvm use 18.17.0`, I uninstalled previous node versions (18.17 is the only one currently installed), opened a new terminal. What am I missing?

---

Per @Konrad's comment, indeed `sudo` gives a different version:

```bash
$ sudo node --version
v18.16.0
```

This is just `sudo`, not `sudo -E` - so this is not an env var issue.   What can this be?

---

Per @Lk77's comment, indeed:

```bash
$ which node
/big/home/ofeks/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin/node
$ sudo which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

but why is that??  `echo $PATH` and `sudo echo $PATH` give identical results.

Comment: Try `sudo -E node --version`

Comment: @Konrad indeed, see edit to the question (doesn't fit in a comment)

Comment: it's expected, because it's not the necessarily the same node binary. try `which node` and `sudo which node`. Also note that -E will not change anything to the used binary

Comment: Aslo, if you are on debian i think $PATH will not be carried over when using sudo -E, it will be reset by sudo, as a security mesure i think

Comment: The issue you're  facing is likely due to the difference between the user's environment and the environment when running commands with sudo.
In general, its good to avoid using `sudo` with nodejs and npm. you simply take the ownership of npm pks with this command: sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/$USER/.npm

Comment: @OfekShilon `sudo -E echo $PATH` is misleading i think, because sudo does something internally and your $PATH is overriden.

Comment: `sudo $(which node) -v` will work as you want, it will retrieve the current node location, and use it in the sudo command

Comment: @Lk77 indeed, turns out `sudo -E echo $PATH` is misleading but not because anything internal in sudo - just that $PATH is expanded before execution, while in regular user.  When I do ` echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh` I see a different PATH, and it is still different in ` echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo -E sh`.   There's a better explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/257666/89706